# newlib-nano long long support

Tags: c, gcc, newlib

I'm developing a program for ARM architecture (bare metal) using a GCC cross compiler (arm-none-eabi-). To keep the code size small, I use a "--specs=nano.specs" linker flag, to link against newlib-nano.
The problem I've ran into is having "long long" support in printf, i.e.:

```
long long int val = 1234;
pritnf("%lld", val);
```

Adding "-u _printf_float" linker flag does not solve this. It does cause the code size to increase by 9kB, but it only seems to be adding float support, without "long long" support. Linking against newlib (removing the "--specs=nano.specs" flag) - although does solve the issue - is not acceptable, as it causes the code size to increase by 46kB.

Are there any flags that re-enable only the "long long" support for newlib-nano version of printf?

Comment: Consider printing it in hex instead, which can be done by simply splitting into two `uint32_t`s and printing those.

Comment: That's not very helpful for printing `-1234LL`

Answer (score 2):

Do not know much about newlib-nano (is it some fork?), but newlib also have no default support for long long specifiers, so may be this will help:

- reconfigure you newlib with `--enable-newlib-io-long-long` flag
- rebuild

Comment: newlib-nano is a cut-down version of newlib. According to this: [link](https://github.com/32bitmicro/newlib-nano-1.0/blob/master/newlib/README.nano) the `enable-newlib-io-long-long` flag is ignored. This seems to answer my question - either newlib needs to be used, or no `long long` support will be possible in case of newlib-nano.

Comment: @JacekŚlimok: Or maybe you can port just the `long long` support from newlib to newlib-nano.

Comment: @KeithThompson I'll take a look into this and see how much effort it'd take to port this single part. I'm assuming however that `enable-newlib-io-long-long` is explicitly mentioned as ignored for a reason.

Comment: Yea, 8 years later - I too have this issue with *chip-vendor* supplied libraries (ie: microsemi and xilinx) - suggesting that I can just reconfigure newlib...  yea, if I was developing my own cross tool chain yes, I could do that and I did that in a previous life. Definitely see advantage of "no-floats" (floats are huge space cost)  but uint64_t is not ..